# Mostrar solo una vez datos repetidos de Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo los siguientes datos en Mysql

> Categoria:

```
Salud y belleza
Tecnología
Tecnología
Cocina y hogar
Tecnología
Salud y belleza
Cocina y hogar
```

Lo que necesito es que al hacer la consulta solo me muestre una vez cada palabra, de este modo:

```
Salud y belleza
Tecnología
Cocina y hogar
```

La verdad no tengo ni la menor idea de como hacerlo, agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas, aquí mi código actual:

```
    //CONSULTA DEL PRODUCTO
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT categoria FROM productos");
    $stmt->execute(); $results = $stmt->get_result(); $categorias = $results->fetch_assoc();
    if ($prodOrodrigin->num_rows >= 1) {
        while($rowCategoria = $results->fetch_assoc()){
             echo $rowCategoria['categoria'];
        }
    }
```

Como les indico, esto me mostrará todas las filas de categoria sin importar que se repitan, lo que necesito es que muestre todas las que hayan sin pero sin repetirse.

Comment: Puedes utilizar `select distinct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más lógico es que tengas una tabla de categorías donde obtener estos datos. Si esto no es así y deseas obtener los datos de la tabla de productos, entonces debes utilizar la cláusula `DISTINCT` en la consulta de SQL.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM productos");
```

Si lo deseas ordenado, utiliza el `ORDER BY`

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT categoria FROM productos ORDER BY categoria");
```

Answer (score 3):

Hola puedes lograrlo de esta manera:

Consula normal:

```
SELECT categoria FROM productos
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#Ahora evitamos las categorias repetidas con "select distinc";

```
select DISTINCT categoria from productos
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#Ahora logramos lo mismo usando GROUP BY y Min():

```
Select MIN(id) as id, categoria FROM productos GROUP BY categoria
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario amigo, funciona perfectamente este método, para los próximos visitantes de mi pregunta: Este método funciona igual y mejor :D